# MUI 5 disable year change in MobileDatePicker

Tags: material-ui

I want to disable the ability to change the year in the mobile date picker I am using

```
import { LocalizationProvider, MobileDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
```

I am on

```
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
```

[image: mobile date picker]

I don't want the user to be able to go into this view
[image: change year view]

I don't see a setting to turn this off does anyone know if there is a prop to set to disable this setting.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the prop **`views`** with an object, where you can put `{['day']}` or `{['day', 'month']}`

```
<LocalizationProvider adapterLocale={es} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <DatePicker
    inputFormat="dd"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    views={['day']}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Here's the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/)